# Issue with defining a variable in a program

Tags: python, function, variables

I am trying to write a simple program that calculates and prints the perfect square numbers up to an input upper bound. My code is:

```
"""Print all the perfect squares from zero up to a given maximum."""

def read_bound():
   """Reads the upper bound from the standard input (keyboard).
      If the user enters something that is not a positive integer
      the function issues an error message and retries
      repeatedly"""
   upper_bound = None
   while upper_bound is None:
       line = input("Enter the upper bound: ")
       if line.isnumeric() and int(line) >= 0:
           upper_bound = int(line)
           return upper_bound
       else:
           print("You must enter a positive number.")



def is_perfect_square(num):
   """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
   for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):
       for candidate in range(1, num):
           if candidate * candidate == num:
               return True



def print_squares(upper_bound, squares):
   """Print a given list of all the squares up to a given upper bound"""


   print("The perfect squares up to {} are: ". format(upper_bound))
   for square in squares:
       print(square, end=' ')



def main():
   """Calling the functions"""
   upper_bound = read_bound()
   squares = []
   for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):
       if is_perfect_square(num):
           squares.append(num)

   print_squares(upper_bound, squares)


   main()
```

However when I run the program and input any valid number, I get an error stating `builtins.NameError: name 'upper_bound' is not defined` on the line that has `for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):`. What is causing this issue and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You don’t pass upper_bound into that function, only num.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has a problem with "is_perfect_square" function. You don't need "upper_bound" for loop as you already have it in "main" function. Your "is_perfect_square" function should be as shown below:

```
def is_perfect_square(num):
   """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
   for candidate in range(1, num):
           if candidate * candidate == num:
               return True
```